# Отсутствует класс Socket

Tags: c#

Создаю библиотеку с такими целевыми платформами: 
[image: 1]
Как использовать класс Socket? Неужели он отсутствует???

Comment: Наверное нужно использовать https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/hh202874(v=vs.105).aspx  Windows.Networking.Sockets и StreamSocket

Answer (score 1):

Да, он отсутствует для данной платформы: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx (в самом низу список поддерживаемых платформ, поддерживается только в Windows Phone Silverlight).

Для каждого класса в MSDN есть информация, на каких платформах он доступен.

Comment: Так а заметь его чем? Я прекрасно знаю, что он отсутствует.

Comment: Похоже, нужно пользоваться классами из [этого](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212061.aspx) пространства имен.